# Rails 4: Saving User selections with a Nested Model Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-activerecord, nested-forms

I'm working on a project where I will need to test users at the end of a section. Using a Nested Model Form I'd like for `users` to be able to select `answers` and have those stored. I'm trying to build it out for myself to improve and could use advice from more experienced developers on how to best approach this.

I am assuming that this is many-to-many through relationship and I would need a joining table but I'm unclear on how to surface it to allow `users` to select their `answers`. Would I need to create a controller for this new joining table or am I misunderstanding `ActiveRecord` in this case?

My Models are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :test
    has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
end
```

Any insight/advice on how to best accomplish my goal would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Watch this video about `nested-forms` http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 1):

There are different solutions you can try. One way is to set up associations between test and answers through questions.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :test
end
```

test.rb

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions, through: :answers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
end
```

question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

answer.rb

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  belongs_to :question
end
```

As for allowing users to select answers, you may need to set up separate associations for an answer to have many selected_answers and many possible_answers through selected_answers. Maybe start with getting tests and answers set up and then move on to selecting answers.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay Margo. I will give it a try and let you know how it goes. Much appreciated from a tired guy :)